# How to retrieve user details from mention tweets?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am in the processing of creating a bot that reads all mentions in userstream Twitter timeline and reply accordingly, however I cannot seem to get the users details who posted the mention in order to reply back, all I receive is the mention status/text.

I am using Python and Tweepy API to achieve this:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream

consumer_key = '********'
consumer_secret = '********'
access_token = '***********'
access_secret = '*********'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

class MyStreamListener (tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)


    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

    def on_direct_message(self, status):
        print(status)


twitterStream = Stream(auth, MyStreamListener())
userStream = twitterStream.userstream()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It needed

```
print(status.author.screen_name)
```